# UITapGestureRecognizer to ignore web link request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UITapGestureRecognizer on my UIViewController. The UIViewController has a UIScrollView which has a UIWebView. Now the problem I am having is how can I ignore the tap if it was going to a link in the UIWebView, in other words when it hits:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

the tap gesture recognizer should be ignored. The problem is there is no way that I can do this. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: You add UITapGestureRecognizer to view or UIWebView?

Comment: I added it to the view, what I want is basically when the shouldStartLoadRequest is called it should disable the tap gesture recognizer

Answer (score 1):

I believe UIWebView installs its own gesture recognizers; thus, you might want to look into implementing:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

with some situational logic.

Comment: I had this implemented.. but then how do I detect if it's a link click from a UIGestureRecognizer